# php form javascript onSubmit won't work

Tags: php, javascript, forms, show-hide, onsubmit

Once again a question...it's almost driving me crazy for hrs :-/

My problem:

I have an upload form on my website and the upload works fine. But I want to give the user a feedback while uploading, cuz it can take a few seconds depending on the file size.

I thought about showing a gif animated progress bar in a div and show it with javascript. I tried it, but it just won't show up when I'm hitting the submit button...and when I'm adding onSubmit="....  return false;" the upload won't work anymore...

here is my code:

in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide() {
var div = document.getElementById('progressBar');
if (div.style.display == 'none') {
 div.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
 div.style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
```

body:

```
 <div id="progressBar" style="display:none;height:40px;width:250px;margin:0px auto;">
 <img src="img/progressbar.gif" alt="Progress Bar">
 </div> 


 <form name="photo" id="upload_big" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" onsubmit="showHide();">
 <input class="linkinput" type="file" name="image" size="20"/>
 <input type="submit" name="upload" id="uploadbutton" value="Upload image"/>
```

I would appreciate any help...and since I'm a rookie -> please help me to get better instead of judging ;-)

Thanks out there!

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML, not the PHP code. The problem **could** well be with the rendered code.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery it makes a lot of things way easier

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(function() {
   $('#upload_big').submit(function() {
      showHide();
   });
});
```

---

Sometimes, the form submission prohibits you from casting anymore JavaScript functionality on the page. To be on the safe side, you should also base functionality not on the form submission event, but on the `<input type="submit">` click:

```
$(function() {
   $('input#uploadbutton').click(function(e) {
      showHide();
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: yep sure I did...even as a rookie ;)

Comment: Updated my answer with another possible solution

Comment: Mhh..no sorry, tried that as well, but didn't work :-/ But could it be what @Licson said? I mean if I set the onSubmit to flase then it works with showing the progressbar, but it won't upload, since it's not going through... Any ideas? I'm desperate...

Comment: Take out the `onSubmit();` attribute, and update your code to add the two extra bits I've just added. Does it still submit the form and fail to show the activity you want?

Comment: Activity is working now...but no uploading anymore :-/ ohhh noo ;-(  btw thanks for your help! So any idea how to fix this now? :D it's killing me...

Answer (score 0):

It's because when the submit event has triggered, the browser already sent the form and will go to another page.

Comment: Ok..get it, but how can I fix this?

Comment: You can consider to use a iframe hack to upload file asynchorously(bad idea but works) or use the new `XMLHttpRequest2`.

Comment: The iframe "hack" is not a bad idea.  It is the BEST choice for uploading asynchronously when using a user agent that does not support the file API.